# Keystone with Supabase?

Tags: keystonejs, supabase-js

I'm using Supabase and I'd like to add CMS functionality. I already have a table called `Profiles`.

When I install Keystone JS and provide my Supabase DB connection details I get this warning:

```
⚠️  Warnings:

  • You are about to drop the `Profiles` table, which is not empty (3 rows).
```

Does this mean that Keystone JS isn't compatible with Supabase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is compatible in the sense that you can use Supabase as the DB for Keystone. However I don't think you can also create custom tables. Essentially Keystone wants to own the database.